# Pegar o valor do input mais próximo de um botão

Tags: jquery, dom

Dado o código abaixo, como chego de `button.like` ou `button.dislike`, no valor do `input#avaliacao_item_id (2)` pelo jQuery?

```
<td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md like">
    0
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md dislike">
    0
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
  </button>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/avaliacoes" class="new_avaliacao" data-remote="true" id="new_avaliacao" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
    <input id="avaliacao_item_id" name="avaliacao[item_id]" type="text" value="2">
    <input id="hidden_tipo" name="avaliacao[avaliacao]" type="hidden">
    <input id="submit_2" name="commit" type="submit" value="Like!">
  </form>
</td>
```

Tenho o seguinte, mas não está funcionando, no debug fala que id está como `undefined`:

```
$('.like').click(function() {
    if (gon.usuario_logado){
        var id = $(this).closest("input#avaliacao_item_id").val();
      $('#hidden_tipo').val(true);
      $('#submit_' + id).click();
    }else
        bootbox.alert("Você deve estar logado para avaliar um item.");
});
```

A idéia é clicar no `button.like` e simular um evento de *click* no `button#submit_[valor do input]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que o `closest()` sobe no DOM e procura elementos pai/ancestrais. E o input é descente de um sibling/irmão, e não ancestral.

O seu código poderia funcionar se usasse como tenho em baixo. Subindo no DOM e voltando a descer com o `find()`:

```
var id = $(this).closest("td").find("input#avaliacao_item_id");
```

mas na verdade sendo que IDs unicas não precisa disso e pode usar somente:

```
var id = $("#avaliacao_item_id").val();
```